Can the SLS's mobile launch platform be rotated at the launch complex to keep the rocket on the leeward side of the tower in case of high winds?
This is a follow-on question from the discussion in the comments of an answer to this question.
Some helpful links:
https://spacenews.com/nasa-investigating-very-minor-artemis-hurricane-damage/

Sadly, no. Take a look at the interfaces of the mobile launcher to the ground systems in this crop from https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-20220915-PH-JNP01_0003/KSC-20220915-PH-JNP01_0003~orig.jpg

You might physically be able to "do a 180" and drive up the hill backwards, but none of the plumbing or electrical connections to the mobile launcher would be where you expected them to be.
(The "180" assumes the support posts are symmetric which they may or may not be, but even if they are, it won't work because of the connection problem)
